# Are there any workarounds or extensions for environment variable support in workspace files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, path, environment-variables

VSCode doesn't support environment variables when specifying paths inside code-workspace files:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44755

There hasn't been an update on this feature request since 2018. In he meantime, are there any workarounds or extensions available?